# Can't tell if my variable is true, then make it true in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

When I select a food in my game, it is supposed to see if the food I picked is similar to the food the customer ordered. If it is the same, I want it to stay as what the customer ordered because I'm displaying an image and the image only displays if they are both the same. After I pick another food, the image I displayed is removed because the variable `food_selected` is now not the same as what the customer ordered. Let me give you a clearer explanation:

Here is what happens when I print:
The customer foods: tomato, lettuce
What the player picked:  tomato, tomato (it puts both tomato and then I still need to pick the lettuce)

The customer foods: tomato, lettuce
What the player picked:  lettuce, lettuce (and now it changes both of them)

What I want:
(When he picks the first food the customer ordered)
The customer foods: tomato, lettuce
What the player picked : tomato, tomato

(When he picks the second food the customer ordered)
The customer foods: tomato, lettuce
What the player picked : tomato, lettuce

Where the problem is happening:

```
if food_selected_1 == food_1:
                    same = True
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(check, (30,30))
                    screen.blit(img, (285, 10))
                else:
                    same = False
                if food_selected_2 == food_2:
                    same = True
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(check, (30,30))
                    screen.blit(img, (285, 70))
                else:
                    same = False
                if same:
                    click_1 = 0
                    click_2 = 0
```

All my code:

```
import pygame
import pdb
import random as r
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((325,325))
running = True
colors = [(199,203,132), (255,0,0), (0,255,0), (84,87,44)]
mouse_pos_x_left = [0.4, 1.98, 3.62, 5.22]
mouse_pos_x_right = [1.26, 2.86, 4.46, 6.06]
foods = ['bread', 'tomato', 'lettuce', 'ham']
food_selected_1 = ''
food_selected_2 = ''
customer1 = pygame.image.load('customer1.png')
food_box = pygame.image.load('food_box.png')
check = pygame.image.load('check.png')
same = False
#rand
random_num_1 = r.randint(1,4)
random_num_2 = r.randint(1,4)
randoms = [1,2,3,4]
food_1 = ''
food_2 = ''
click_1 = 0
click_2 = 0
able = False
clicked = [False,False,False,False]
"""Bugs:
- when selected same food as customer and clicked on other food it removes checkmark
- when clicked on food shows checkmark for a sec
- when selected same food as customer and then chose another same food as customer first checkmark removes 
"""

while running:
    same_foods = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        screen.fill((255,255,255))
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mouse_x = pos[0] / 50
        mouse_y = pos[1] / 50
        mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        #draw foods:
        for i in range(4):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (colors[i]), (17 + 80 * i, 265, 50, 50))
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), (17 + 80 * i, 265, 50, 50),5)
            if mouse_x > mouse_pos_x_left[i] and mouse_x < mouse_pos_x_right[i]:
                if mouse_y > 5.4 and mouse_y < 6.26:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,255,255), (17 + 80 * i, 265, 50, 50), 5)
                    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                        click_1 += 1
                        food_selected_1 = foods[i]
                        food_selected_2 = foods[i]
                        #clicked[i] is either the first image or second and...
                        clicked[i] = True
            if clicked[i]:
                screen.blit(check, (17 + 80 * i, 210, 50, 50))  
            if click_1 == 2:
                click_2 = 1
                click_1 = 1
            if click_1 == 2:
                click_2 = 1
        #customer:
        customer1_img = pygame.transform.scale(customer1, (150,150))
        food_box_img = pygame.transform.scale(food_box, (100, 125))
        screen.blit(customer1_img, (50,50))
        screen.blit(food_box_img, (170,0))
        #random food:
        for i in range(4):
            #if random number is == 1 
            if random_num_1 == randoms[i]:
                #then food_1 == to the first food
                food_1 = foods[i]
                #then draw the first food 
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (colors[i]), (195, 5, 50, 50))
            if random_num_2 == randoms[i]:
                food_2 = foods[i]
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (colors[i]), (195, 60, 50, 50))
            if food_1 == food_2:
                same_foods = True
                if click_1 == 1:
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(check, (30,30))
                    screen.blit(img, (285, 10))
                if click_2 == 1:
                    screen.blit(img, (285, 70))
            if same_foods == False:
                if food_selected_1 == food_1:
                    same = True
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(check, (30,30))
                    screen.blit(img, (285, 10))
                else:
                    same = False
                if food_selected_2 == food_2:
                    same = True
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(check, (30,30))
                    screen.blit(img, (285, 70))
                else:
                    same = False
                if same:
                    click_1 = 0
                    click_2 = 0
    print(food_selected_1, food_1)
    print(food_selected_2, food_2)
    pygame.display.flip()
    pass
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand what you are saying, but I'm guessing from the code you wrote that you want `same` to only be `True` when both `food_1` and `food_2` are the same as the selected ones.

You need something like this:

```py
                if food_selected_1 == food_1:
                    same_1 = True
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(check, (30,30))
                    screen.blit(img, (285, 10))
                else:
                    same_1 = False
                if food_selected_2 == food_2:
                    same_2 = True
                    img = pygame.transform.scale(check, (30,30))
                    screen.blit(img, (285, 70))
                else:
                    same_2 = False
                if same_1 and same_2:
                    click_1 = 0
                    click_2 = 0
```

Comment: no what im saying that i want to happen is when i click on a food which is stored in the food_selected variable and it is similar to the food the customer picked which i stored in the food_1 or food_2 variable keep the food_selected the same thing as the food the customer ordered but that is not what is happening because i cant figure out how to do it.